# Use regex to find a certain instance of two characters

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I am not sure how to approach this problem using regex.

> Write a method that takes a string in and returns true if the letter "z" appears within three letters after an "a". You may assume that the string contains only lowercase letters.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
def foo s
  !!(s =~ /a\w{,2}z/)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you're being asked to match any of the following patterns:

```
'a**z'
'a*z'
'az'
```

where `*` is a lowercase letter, a-z. In natural language (ok, English) that can be stated as "An 'a' followed by 0, 1, or 2 lowercase letters, followed by a 'z'. Regex-wise, that can be expressed as

```
/a[a-z]{0,2}z/
```

I'm not a rubyist at all, so there may or may not be some sort of Ruby specific tweaks that need to be made to that, but that should be the basic gist of it.

Comment: your Regex will hit on other characters besides a.

Comment: Are you talking about the characters between the 'a' and the 'z'? If I'm reading the question right, then it *should* match any lowercase letters in those spots.

Answer (score -1):

This is the site I like to use for Ruby Regex validations. rubular.com That being said, if you want to hit on a z that is 0 to 2 spaces after only an a, and the text is lowercase I would use this Regex string. [a]{0,2}z This regex string passed all three scenarios on Rubular and it will only hit on an a.

Comment: just fyi, that actually matches 0, 1 or 2 'a's followed by a 'z', which will match almost anything that has a 'z' in it.